# Raspberry Camera Module not working on Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (octopi)

Tags: camera, rpi-update

I am trying to use a new Camera Module V2 (8MP) on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+, but it seems that the Raspberry couldn't see the camera.

So I started to investigate. Checking the `octopi` version that is running onthe board:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OctoPrint version : 1.3.12
OctoPi version    : 0.17.0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In particular:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ uname -a
Linux octopi 4.19.93-v7+ #1290 SMP Fri Jan 10 16:39:50 GMT 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

First of all I ensured that the CSI ribbon is properly plugged (checked the right side and checked the right port, the one near HMDI port).

Secondly, I enabled the camera using `sudo raspi-config`:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Then I run `sudo reboot`.

Thirdly, I checked the availability of the camera by running:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0
```

I am surprised that `detected` is `0`. So I turned off the Raspberry and checked again the correct installation of the ribbon at [official documentation](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/quickstart.html). After rebooting it I checked the `vcgencmd`, but I still get `detected=0`.

I run:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo apt update
...
All packages are up to date.
```

then

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo apt upgrade
...
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Obviously. Finally I launched:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo rpi-update
...
Backing up modules 4.19.93-v7+
...
```

I am stuck at this point because I get and error of regular file busy `/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd`, I tried to looking for which process is using this file:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo lsof /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd
```

But I get no output. Do someone can help me what is wrong and how to make the Camera working?

I am not sure that it could be a power issue, but there are no other peripherals attached on the board, except the camera itself.

---

> Update

After trying many times to `rpi-update` finally succeded:

```
sudo rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
```

So, rebooted, **raspi-config > Camera enable** and then:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0
```

So, apparently nothing changed, the problem still remains. Last chance: I tried to use an unofficial CSI Camera (with IR), rebooting and launching:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
```

Wow! So I launched:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ raspistill -o test.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I relaunch the `rpi-update` and I get:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ sudo rpi-update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
```

At this point I have no more idea of what to do.

> Note: I am using the original power cable given when I bought the Raspberry.

Comment: I am start supposing that the Camera Module may be broken, but I would to be sure before return it to Amazon.

Comment: The camera is broken, or the ribbon cable isn't connected, or you've got the ribbon cable the wrong way round, or you've got the ribbon cable in the wrong connector, or the small "SUNNY" connector on the camera board needs re-seating.

Comment: Yes, I tried to change ribbon cable, but nothing works. Using the unofficial pi camera, both ribbons works. So... yes, this Camera V2 is broken. Thanks

Comment: Toss that Chinese cloned junk camera in the trash and buy the supported 8MP version.

Comment: It was an original Raspi Camera V2 bought from Amazon for 30€. xD Returned and refunded, perfect. The Chinese clone was the one that now still works. lol